# Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching

Tags: caching

I am using enterprise library cache in my application. Cache is common so data related to different sessions is stored in the shared cache. What i want is that when a user logs out or session expires i remove only those items for the cache which belongs to this specific session. All such items that have a key like

SessionID_somekeyforsomething

where SessionID is a GUID generated for each session.

The flush function clears the entire cache. So i cant use this as the cache is being shared between multiple sessions. 
The Remove(string key) requires the exact key.I cant use this as i don't have exact keys for cache item belonging to a specific session. I just the initial part of the keys.

How can i achieve my objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the CacheManager in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching is not an enumerable class, and the only way to get a cached item is knowing its key (through the .Item property or the getData data method which I think they're basically the same), you must cache item lists instead of individual items. Each list would contain all the cached objects related to a session.

For example, when a new session is started, create a new **Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, object>>** and add it to the cache.

The key of the first dictionary would be the sessionID, and its value would be another dictionary whose keys are the keys of the objects to be cached (for that session), and their values would be the objects themselves.

When you need and object, you must have the SessionID (to get the corresponding dictionary), and the object key to get the cached item from that dictionary.

When a session is terminated, just find the dictionary corresponding to the session and remove it from main dictionary.

A problem with this approach is that scavenging could affect several objects at once, since complete lists could be scavenged instead of single objects. For this, a refresh policy could be implemented in order to re-cache the dictionaries (and even clean them up).